# How to copy files from one git repo to another git repo in Azure pipelines task?

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

There is one public source repo in github where all the source code is present. There is another github repo of mine which has some configuration files.
I want to run some tests of source repo using the configuration file present in my github repo using Azure pipeline task.

How can I checkout to source repo of github first and then do initial setup like build in that repo? And after that copy configuration files from my another github repo to the source repo directory and run tests of source repo.
I want to do these steps in Azure yaml pipelines as from azure release pipelines not all the artifacts are accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking out multiple repos is possible, also with GitHub as a source, but don't forget to setup a [GitHub service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#github-service-connection).

More info and options about this see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#specify-multiple-repositories

Since you want the GitHub repo to trigger the Azure DevOps pipeline, please check out the feature that is available since October 2022:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/github-actions?view=azure-devops